# Scrolling iframe inside div with rounded corners leaves trail of rounded corners

Tags: css, iframe, rounded-corners

I have a primary HTML page onwhich I created a DIV with a CSS top-left rounded corner.  It appears fine and as expected.  Inside the DIV is an iframe which I use to display additional pages.  This too works fine and as expected.  My problem is that when I scroll down a page in the iframe, then scroll back up, the div/iframe shows "tails", or remanents of the rounded corner along the sides. I've tried creating a DIV in the seperate page with background-color just after that page's body tag; no change.  I see this problem in both IE9 and Chrome.  Can someone explain to me why this happens, or better - what I need to do to prevent this from displaying?  Or direct me to a site that covers this?  Much appreciated.

CSS:

```
#contentDIV{position:fixed;top:3.8em;left:13.5em;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:auto;-moz-border-radius-topleft:.8em;border-top-left-radius:.8em;}
#contentFRAME{width:100%;height:99%;top:0;overflow:auto;border-width:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Best to create a minimal stand-alone test case. Take the code that you have, make a copy of it and start removing stuff, save, reload and repeat. If the issue resolves without effecting something then you've found out how to eliminate it otherwise see step 2. I'm not sure about posting URL's, you can try and I didn't see anything in the FAQ for or against it.

2.) If you can figure out how to cut out the issue yourself without causing the issue great however often you have to use the code in a certain way. Go ahead and post the minimal test case for others to recreate the issue.

3.) One thing you can do is use web developer tools to remove CSS rules (like Firebug for Firefox) and see if the issue is resolved by disabling certain rules. Enable a rule if disabling that rule doesn't resolve the issue. Issues are almost always caused by a combination of two or more sets of code/conditions.

Also there is no "body tag", you're referencing the body element. It's highly desirable to use the correct terminology for two reasons: first you look professional and second you greatly increase the chances that someone will understand what you're talking about. The term tag is only applicable in 0.1% of instances it's used, it actually refers to the individual tags, not the element itself. An example of the term tag being correctly used would be, "In XHTML does the meta element have a closing tag (< meta > < / meta >) or is it a self-closing element (< meta / >)?

Comment: (forgive me if I double-post...it doesn't appear that my first response uploaded)  Thanks for the response and suggestion.  I followed your advise and removed stuff to pin-point the issue.  Turned out to be defining a default background color on the body element.  I still don't understand yet just why, but it resolved my issue.

Comment: What browsers / versions are you testing? Can you post some code? Separate chunks for each file (three total, one CSS, two (X)HTML because of the iframe) and hopefully we can iron the issue out completely for you. I'm crashing for the night though I'll be around tomorrow so no huge rush.